# How do I authorize users to AWS CloudFront using Auth0?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, authorization, amazon-cloudfront, auth0

I am attempting to restrict access to S3 content through AWS CloudFront to authorized users only, using Auth0 as my authorizer.

I have set up a Lambda@Edge function, but I am uncertain about the code to include. Specifically, I wish to authorize users to access only the files they own, which are prefixed by the Auth0 "sub" value present in the JWT token.

Also if I am trying to authorize users before accessing content would I trigger this function at the "Viewer Request" stage?

Stack: AWS S3, AWS CloudFront, AWS Lambda@Edge

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source code repository (with an accompanying article) on how to accomplish what you are asking: [aws-lamgda-edge-oauth](https://github.com/experoinc/aws-lambda-edge-oauth)